# how to use one class variables into another class

Tags: java, class, variables

I am newbie to coding in java... I am trying to implement a program that illustartes multi-tasking.There while programming I am struck with a small task,which I am unable to find out a way for it.Getting in to the details,I have 3 classes where if I declare variables individually,I am successful in accomplishing my tasks,but I want a requirement in such a way that,I want to use variables of one class in another.Even though I am declaring the variables as public,it is throwing an exception/error.Here is my implementation code for clear understanding for experts out there!

```
class TrainReservation extends Thread
{
    public int trainAvailability=1, bearthAvailability=1;
    int noOfSeats;
    TrainReservation(int noOfSeats)
    {
        this.noOfSeats=noOfSeats;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        if((trainAvailability >= noOfSeats) && (bearthAvailability >= noOfSeats))
        {
            System.out.println("seat is reserved");
            trainAvailability=trainAvailability-noOfSeats;
            bearthAvailability=bearthAvailability-noOfSeats;
            System.out.println(trainAvailability);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("no seats available");
    }
}
class TrainReservationCancel extends Thread
{
    int trainAvailability;
    trainAvailability=tr.trainAvailability;
    int noOfSeats;
    TrainReservationCancel(int noOfSeats)
    {
        this.noOfSeats=noOfSeats;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        if(noOfSeats!=0)
        {
            bearthAvailability=bearthAvailability+noOfSeats;
            trainAvailability=trainAvailability+noOfSeats;
            System.out.println(bearthAvailability);
        }
    }
}
class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TrainReservation tr=new TrainReservation(2);
        TrainReservationCancel tr1=new TrainReservationCancel(1);
        Thread obj=new Thread(tr);
        tr.start();
        Thread obj1= new Thread(tr1);
        tr1.start();
    }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of where the error is

[image]

Any help would be great for me and appreciated.

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: What exception/error is thrown, and where exactly? Please add full stack trace.

Comment: `trainAvailability=tr.trainAvailability;` What is this `tr` ?

Comment: @shan Its an Object of train availability class

Comment: @PéterTörök Please see the edited question(post),I have placed my error screen shot,thanks

Comment: @Eshwar, But i don't see the `tr` variable inside your class. You should declare it inside your `TrainReservationCancel` class. You have a `tr` variable inside `MainClass`. you should pass it to the `TrainReservationCancel` class.

Comment: @shan But tr is an object of train reservation class,by using this object,I am trying to call availability variable in train reservation cancel class

Comment: @Eshwar, Ok... You have 3 classes called `TrainReservation `, `TrainReservationCancel` and `MainClass`. these are separate classes. you have `TrainReservation tr` and `TrainReservationCancel tr1` variables inside the **MainClass**. Then how `TrainReservationCancel` can access `tr` variable. it is inside the `MainClass`. you should pass it to the `TrainReservationCancel`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compile error, not an Exception which is useful to know including which line.

You are using `tr` but you don't pass it to the TrainReservationCancel class.

try changing your constructor to take a TrainReservation

```
TrainReservationCancel(int noOfSeats, TrainReservation tr)
{
    this.noOfSeats=noOfSeats;
    this.trainAvailability=tr.trainAvailability;
}
```

and in main

```
TrainReservation tr=new TrainReservation(2);
TrainReservationCancel tr1=new TrainReservationCancel(1, tr);
```

BTW: You want to make your classes `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`

Comment: and the same goes about using bearthAvailability in TrainReservationCancel run method

Comment: @peter lawrey But even after implementing what u suggested,nothing worked our way,please help me,thanks for concern anyway!

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing worked our way"? Do you mean you have the same errors? Do you mean you have new error? Do you mean that your program now compiles after you fixed the rest of the rror in your code but the program does work?

Comment: @Eshwar, "nothing worked our way" contains zero information about your actual problem, making it impossible to help you. Please learn to ask good questions, including all the relevant information needed to solve the problems. Such as: what is the exact error you observe, where it happens, what is the input and the expected / actual output?

Comment: If you want to use `tr` in another method, you need to save it as a field in your constructor and use `tr.bearthAvailability` instead.

Comment: When you say "nothing works", it implies you have not idea what you are doing. This could be because you are new to Java, but it could also be you are tired and can't think about your problem any more and you want others to do the thinking for you. For us the problem is we don't know what the problem is nor do we know what you don't understand so we have to guess which means more work for us. :(

Comment: The bigest problem is that writing thread safe code is 10x harder than passing an object from one class to another.  I wouldn't recommend anyone write multi-threaded code until they a) can write code which compiles, b) can use a profiler to prove they need to use multiple threads. Professional developers with 5 years experience often find writing concurrent code difficult.

Answer (score 0):

trainAvailability=tr.trainAvailability;
tr not declared in this class

if your doing this in a threaded environment and reading variables you would also be best declaring them as volatile